# What's the correct (British) pronunciation of 'the'?

Tags: definite-article, pronunciation

I've been an English student since school, however, I always feel like I'm mispronouncing the word "the".

Oxford online dictionary defines the pronunciation of 'the' as: /ðə/, /ðiː/, /ðɪ/.
So, are the three correct in every situation?, if not, when should I use each of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct pronunciation of "the"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123348/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parallels the use of "a" and "an".

/ðə/ is used before a consonant.

/ðɪ/ is used before a vowel. (Some people might use /ðiː/, but I imagine this would used for emphasis.)

A bit more explanation here:
[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page16.shtml)

Comment: I pronounce it exactly the same way (*-uh*), regardless of it coming before a consonant or vowel. *Unless* I intend to emphasize something, then I pronounce it the other way (*-ee*), again regardless of if it coming before a consonant or vowel.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple,
We pronounce ðɪ before a word which starts with a vowel sound like the (ðɪ) apple and in case of a consonant sound, we pronounce ðə, for an example the (ðə) car.
And,
ði: is pronounced to emphasise a situation.